# How to make this code repetitive?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is the block of code:

```
{{ Form::open() }}
<input type="number" name="part_number" placeholder="Part Number" />
<input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
<input type="number" name="annual_usage" placeholder="Annual Usage" />
<input type="submit" value="Add Part" />
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I want to make it so the user can add multiple parts but currently I can only add one.  Should I be using a loop or something?

Comment: what would be inside the form??

Comment: Or something.. Correct.

Comment: What is a "part" and how would you like it to be added with or without page reload?

Comment: if u want it repetitive the you have to use loop.save it in a partial file and include that file inside the loop.

Comment: Note that changing the names to stuff like `name="part_number[]"` allow you to have an array of data.

Comment: Could I bring in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {{-- form goes here --}}
@endfor
```

See the [Blade documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/templates) for more info.

Comment: I got an error undefined i, how do I fix that?

Comment: Can you post your code? This was tested before posting, so it should work.

Comment: @for($i=0; i<0; $i++)
{{ Form::open() }}
<input type="number" name="part_number" placeholder="Part Number" />
<input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
<input type="number" name="annual_usage" placeholder="Annual Usage" />
<input type="submit" value="Add Part" />
{{ Form::close() }}
@endfor

Comment: In your @for($i=0; i<0; $i++), the $i in the condition part is missing a $. It should look like this: @for($i=0; $i<0; $i++)

Comment: thank you vlad that was it.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what is in the form, I would suggest you take a look at [Hogan.js](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/). This is a neat little templating engine which works with [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/).

The latter allows you to write code like this:

```
{{#list_items}}
    // code repeated for each list item
{{/list_items}}
{{^list_items}}
    // code to be executed if there are no list items
{{/list_items}}
```